# Find range and number of positions with zero

Tags: r

I have two excel file

[image]

And,

[image]

I want to know the range and positions with 0 coverage values and an output as follows:

[image]

Where,

```
size = (end - start)+1

mapped = positions with > 0 Coverage

%mapped = (mapped/size)*100

Completeness = (Total mapped/Total Size)*100
```

for e.g for the above output Completeness = ((3+2)/(7+5))*100 = 41.66%

I have several such input files to be analyzed. How can I do this in R?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your question is very broad and very unhelpful. 1) use example data and not images. 2) Have a look at the great documentation of how to filter data in R. There is loads about this online and it should most certainly help you

Answer (score 0):

To get to know which part of a data.frame satisfies some condition, you can use `which`, will give you all the indexes for which that condition is `TRUE`, so you can use that to get the parts you're interested in.

If we assume you have a data.frame called `df1` for the first part of your question, and the second image is called `df2`, then you can get the index-range of the rows in df1 with 'chr1' like this:
`range <- which(df1$chr=='chr1')[df2$start[1]]:which(df1$chr=='chr1')[df2$end[1]]`
or instead of manually typing 'chr1', you can use `df2$chr[1]`.
For the count, `sum(df1[range, 'coverage'] > 0)` tells you how many values are more then zero.

Now we need to do that for all rows together, we can use sapply to do something for all values provided:

```
df2$mapped <- sapply(1:nrow(df2), function(row) {
    range <- which(df1$chr==df2$chr[row])[df2$start[row]]:which(df1$chr==df2$chr[row])[df2$end[row]]
    sum(df1[range, 'coverage'] > 0)
}
```

Your other questions are easier answered then asked, as in R most functions are vectorised: you can do something for multiple values at the same time.

```
df2$size = (df2$end - df2$start)+1
df2$perc_mapped = (df2$mapped/df2$size)*100
```

Completeness is just a total of all rows together, `sum(df2$size)` and `sum(df2$mapped)`